# Installing GeoTrace plugin in QGIS on Mac OSX?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, assertionerror

I am trying to install the experimental plugin called GeoTrace in QGIS 3.2 on Mac OSX.

Error message is as follows:

```
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/tools/install_dependencies.py", line 116, in install
  import gttracetool
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 665, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/tools/gttracetool.py", line 40, in 
  import gttrace as trace
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 665, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/tools/gttrace.py", line 33, in 
  from skimage.graph import route_through_array
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/qgis/utils.py", line 665, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skimage'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/geo_trace.py", line 188, in open_trace
  self.dlg = GeoTraceDialog(self.iface)
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/geo_trace_dialog.py", line 62, in __init__
  self.setup_gui()
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/geo_trace_dialog.py", line 85, in setup_gui
  installer.Installer().install() #lol
File "/Users/petergriffin/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/GeoTrace/tools/install_dependencies.py", line 119, in install
  assert False, "An unexpected import error occurred"
  AssertionError: An unexpected import error occurred
```

Comment: install  [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html) (`No module named 'skimage'`)